# How to add a scrollview edge color effect in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-5.0-lollipop

In my app I change the overscroll glow effect color like this:

```
int glowDrawableId = contexto.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
Drawable androidGlow = contexto.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
assert androidGlow != null;
androidGlow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.MyColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

But when i updated to lollipop this code crashes. I get following error code:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myproject.myapp, PID: 954
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:724)
```

Seems that overscroll_glow resource is missing in lollipop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In general, you should never try to reference framework-private resources like that. They are not guaranteed to persist across OS updates or even between different OEM-customized versions of the same OS.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can specify `android:colorEdgeEffect` in your theme to change the overscroll glow color within your entire app. By default, this inherits the primary color value set by `android:colorPrimary`.

res/values/themes.xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="...">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Alternatively, you can modify this value for a single view using an inline theme overlay.

res/values/themes.xml:

```
<!-- Note that there is no parent style or additional attributes specified. -->
<style name="MyEdgeOverlayTheme">
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

res/layout/my_layout.xml:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyEdgeOverlayTheme" />
```

Comment: I get the following eroor using that method. Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorEdgeEffect'.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been android:colorEdgeEffect.

Comment: @alanv Do you know a way of changing the glow color programmatically? In my app I change the status bar and toolbar color programmatically depending on context and would be nice change the overscroll glow color too. I've found that the new Contacts app in Lollipop changes depending on the contact.

Comment: @MrBrightside If you want to use the standard widgets, it can be done via reflection... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27451249/82788 (second part of the answer, ugly but works). If you had a custom widget instead then you could use a custom `EdgeEffect` and it wouldn't be so kludgy.

Answer (score 11):

The `"android:colorEdgeEffect"` solution works perfectly, and is much better than the previous hacks. However, it cannot be used if the edge color needs to be changed prorgrammatically.

It is *possible*, though, to use reflection to do so, setting the `EdgeEffect` objects directly in the `AbsListView` or `ScrollView` instances. For example:

```
EdgeEffect edgeEffectTop = new EdgeEffect(this);
edgeEffectTop.setColor(Color.RED);

EdgeEffect edgeEffectBottom = new EdgeEffect(this);
edgeEffectBottom.setColor(Color.RED);

try {
    Field f1 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowTop");
    f1.setAccessible(true);
    f1.set(listView, edgeEffectTop);

    Field f2 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowBottom");
    f2.setAccessible(true);
    f2.set(listView, edgeEffectBottom);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[`EdgeEffect.setColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html#setColor%28int%29) was added in Lollipop.

Same caveats as any reflection-based solution, though.

Answer (score 4):

In lollipop the overscroll effect color can be customized with the item style colorPrimary :

```
<style name="MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mycolor</item>
</style>
```

This item also affect the color of the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this to change the edge color programmatically on android L. This works for both listView and scrollView, and views extend them.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static void setEdgeEffectL(View scrollableView, int color) {
    final String[] edgeGlows = {"mEdgeGlowTop", "mEdgeGlowBottom", "mEdgeGlowLeft", "mEdgeGlowRight"};
    for (String edgeGlow : edgeGlows) {
        Class<?> clazz = scrollableView.getClass();
        while (clazz != null) {
            try {
                final Field edgeGlowField = clazz.getDeclaredField(edgeGlow);
                edgeGlowField.setAccessible(true);
                final EdgeEffect edgeEffect = (EdgeEffect) edgeGlowField.get(scrollableView);
                edgeEffect.setColor(color);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`overscroll_glow.png` doesn't exist in platform 21. You can copy the resourses from platform 20 and use them.

You can find `overscroll_glow.png` in:

> {SDK_FOLDER}\platforms\android-20\data\res

This way you don't use reflection that can, as you can see, mess with your program after some updates.

Answer (score 0):

i know i am too late, but this works for me for my app api >=17:

```
<style name="ListTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<ListView   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ListTheme"/>
```