# How to change the color of overscroll edge and overscroll glow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, overscroll

How to Change color of over-scroll edge and over-scroll glow or how to change the white color (default color) of android release 5.0 lollipop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android lollipop scrollview edge effect color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104521/android-lollipop-scrollview-edge-effect-color)

Answer (score 92):

The overscroll glow color inherits the primary color value set by `android:colorPrimary` in your entire app. But If you need to specify different value simply use `android:colorEdgeEffect` (only available for API 21 and above).

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="...">
   <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Note that `android:colorPrimary` also sets the color of your ActionBar or Toolbar. Whereas `android:colorEdgeEffect` is more specific and only applies to ListViews, RecyclerViews, etc.

Answer (score 24):

On `LOLLIPOP` the edge glow inherits from `colorPrimary`. After the view is created the edge glow color can only be changed through reflection. This can be useful when you load colors dynamically using `Palette`.

**EDIT: TL;DR:** Download the whole class from here:
https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/71b5c65689786b1d52d701d81d8c7445495807c3/commons/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/widget/XpEdgeEffect.java

**PROGUARD SETUP:** If you're going to use this on widgets from support library you need to keep the field names. Quickest way to do it is the following (although still wasteful):

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat {
    <fields>;    
}
```

Create a utility class with the following code:

```
private static final Class<?> CLASS_SCROLL_VIEW = ScrollView.class;
private static final Field SCROLL_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_TOP;
private static final Field SCROLL_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_BOTTOM;

private static final Class<?> CLASS_LIST_VIEW = AbsListView.class;
private static final Field LIST_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_TOP;
private static final Field LIST_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_BOTTOM;

static {
  Field edgeGlowTop = null, edgeGlowBottom = null;

  for (Field f : CLASS_SCROLL_VIEW.getDeclaredFields()) {
    switch (f.getName()) {
      case "mEdgeGlowTop":
        f.setAccessible(true);
        edgeGlowTop = f;
        break;
      case "mEdgeGlowBottom":
        f.setAccessible(true);
        edgeGlowBottom = f;
        break;
    }
  }

  SCROLL_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_TOP = edgeGlowTop;
  SCROLL_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_BOTTOM = edgeGlowBottom;

  for (Field f : CLASS_LIST_VIEW.getDeclaredFields()) {
    switch (f.getName()) {
      case "mEdgeGlowTop":
        f.setAccessible(true);
        edgeGlowTop = f;
        break;
      case "mEdgeGlowBottom":
        f.setAccessible(true);
        edgeGlowBottom = f;
        break;
    }
  }

  LIST_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_TOP = edgeGlowTop;
  LIST_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_BOTTOM = edgeGlowBottom;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void setEdgeGlowColor(AbsListView listView, int color) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    try {
      EdgeEffect ee;
      ee = (EdgeEffect) LIST_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_TOP.get(listView);
      ee.setColor(color);
      ee = (EdgeEffect) LIST_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_BOTTOM.get(listView);
      ee.setColor(color);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void setEdgeGlowColor(ScrollView scrollView, int color) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    try {
      EdgeEffect ee;
      ee = (EdgeEffect) SCROLL_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_TOP.get(scrollView);
      ee.setColor(color);
      ee = (EdgeEffect) SCROLL_VIEW_FIELD_EDGE_GLOW_BOTTOM.get(scrollView);
      ee.setColor(color);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was looking for a way of changing the glow color programmatically and every answer was related to setting the style on xml. Yours worked for me without a problem and now I can change the color dinamycally depending on the context like I do for the statusbarcolor and the toolbar. Thanks!

Comment: thank you. it works nice. but what about `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: @sajad Here's the class I use to handle the majority of scrolling containers http://pastebin.com/TAujMUu9 The only missing one is `HorizontalScrollView` I think.

Comment: @Analizer Correct, the pastebin code crashes on Android 4. Luckily I found out yesterday so here's the update: http://pastebin.com/JSefcHiB

Comment: ViewPager is missing, I need this exact same thing but for ViewPagers!

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes You have Android source code and my source code at your disposal, I'm sure you can adapt it for ViewPager.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thing is I'm not very good with reflections and I searched a little and couldn't find the source for the updated ViewPager, only an old version (that propably doesn't have the overscroll effect, as it was pre-lollipop): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes On that page you can pick different version from a spinner on top. Check the link in the answer I updated it for ViewPager. Haven't tested but should work.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I tested it, but unfortunately it did not work. You implemented it for the support v4 ViewPager? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes If you need it for v13 ViewPager all you have to do is change `v4` to `v13` in the `import` line at the top of the file.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I mustn't have expressed myself correctly... I'm already using v4, and I was wondering if you made it for this version, which is now clear you did. But it does not work...

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes Fixed. (And there's no v13 ViewPager of course.)

Comment: @EugenPechanec thank you very much, it is working now!

Comment: @EugenPechanec, what about webviews, just realized those can be scrollable too and also have the edge effect!

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes Correct. Since Android 4.4 WebView implementation is provided by an independent APK and I don't want to dig into that. For older devices I just don't care. Feel free to explore if this interests you.

Comment: @EugenPechanec makes sense, I'll look into it! Thanks.

Comment: This Link is broken, btw. (https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/master/android/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/widget/XpEdgeEffect.java)

Answer (score 19):

If you're using the latest RecyclerView implementation it is pretty straightforward to change the overflow colour programmatically. Use the following code (Kotlin implementation):

```
recyclerView.edgeEffectFactory = object : RecyclerView.EdgeEffectFactory() {
    override fun createEdgeEffect(view: RecyclerView, direction: Int): EdgeEffect {
        return EdgeEffect(view.context).apply { setColor(color) }
    }
}
```

Note that this works only for API level 21 (Lollipop) and above. If you know the value at compile time, use the `colorEdgeEffect` as pointed out by Ahmed.

Comment: For java...


`getRecyclerView().setEdgeEffectFactory(new RecyclerView.EdgeEffectFactory() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            protected EdgeEffect createEdgeEffect(@NonNull RecyclerView view, int direction) {
                EdgeEffect edge = new EdgeEffect(view.getContext());
                edge.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(), R.color.blue));
                return edge;
            }
        });`

Answer (score 1):

In pre-lollipop the glow effect is actually a Drawable embedded in the OS's resources, you can apply a ColorFilter on that:

```
public static void changeOverScrollGlowColor(Resources res, int colorID ) {
    try {
        final int glowDrawableId = res.getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
        final Drawable overscrollGlow = res.getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
        overscrollGlow.setColorFilter(res.getColor(colorID), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        final int edgeDrawableId = res.getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
        final Drawable overscrollEdge = res.getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
        overscrollEdge.setColorFilter(res.getColor(colorID), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Calling it once in onCreate is enough.

```
changeOverScrollGlowColor(getResources(), R.color.colorPrimary);
```