# How to change color of the scroll limit in android studio

Tags: android, scroll, colors

I don't know if this is the correct name to design this but I will add an image to show what I want to do.

As you can see, when you are in the scroll limit, something like a colored wave appears. How could I change that color?

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342957/how-to-change-the-color-of-overscroll-edge-and-overscroll-glow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to customise the AppTheme as I did:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Add your color to the attribute "colorEdgeEffect".

```
<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

And your problem will be solved

**NOTE:** This will only work for API 21 and above