# Change TapDown Color on ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and when the user taps down on the item it looks like this.

[image]

This is what it looks like noramally:

[image]

How do I change this default light blue color?

I need the color to be set programatically in the activity file, as it is not always the same color, and also how do you change the color of the fuzzy stuff that comes up at the bottom of a ListView when you continue to scroll down?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

Also how do you change the tap down color of the action bar back button,

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the row color, you need to create a [`StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) and [set it as the **selector** for the `ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

The states to include should be, at least:

- pressed (`android.R.attr.state_pressed`)
- selected (`android.R.attr.state_selected`)
- "normal" (empty state list)

For each state you can set any drawable. If what you need is a plain color, you can programmatically create a [`ColorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) on the spot.

For example:

```
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
ColorDrawable red = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
ColorDrawable transparent = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);

selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, red);
selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected }, red);
selector.addState(new int[] { }, transparent);

listView.setSelector(selector);
```

---

As for the "fuzzy stuff that comes up at the bottom", it's slightly more complicated.

- Prior to Android 5.0 there was no public API for changing it.
- In Lollipop it can be set via the theme, but not programmatically.

For pre-5.0 there is a well-known workaround ([described here](http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/)) which involves tampering with the drawables that are used. However this solution crashes in 5.0, because those resources do not exist anymore.

For Android 5.0, if a static color is acceptable, you can just [configure the new theme attribute `android:colorEdgeEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104521/android-lollipop-scrollview-edge-effect-color) (which is the same as `android:colorPrimary` by default).

If a programmatic solution for Android 5.0 is necessary, you could alternatively change the `EdgeEffect` objects that the ListView has internally using reflection. I've tested this and it works, though it's not the prettiest code:

```
EdgeEffect edgeEffectTop = new EdgeEffect(this);
edgeEffectTop.setColor(Color.RED);

EdgeEffect edgeEffectBottom = new EdgeEffect(this);
edgeEffectBottom.setColor(Color.RED);

try {
    Field f1 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowTop");
    f1.setAccessible(true);
    f1.set(listView, edgeEffectTop);

    Field f2 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowBottom");
    f2.setAccessible(true);
    f2.set(listView, edgeEffectBottom);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Therefore, a full programmatic solution may run something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    // For Android >= 5.0, use setColor() on EdgeEffect
    EdgeEffect edgeEffectTop = new EdgeEffect(this);
    edgeEffectTop.setColor(Color.RED);

    EdgeEffect edgeEffectBottom = new EdgeEffect(this);
    edgeEffectBottom.setColor(Color.RED);

    try {
        Field f1 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowTop");
        f1.setAccessible(true);
        f1.set(listView, edgeEffectTop);

        Field f2 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowBottom");
        f2.setAccessible(true);
        f2.set(listView, edgeEffectBottom);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else
{
    // For Android < 5.0, change overscroll_glow and overscroll_edge
    int glowDrawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
    Drawable androidGlow = getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
    androidGlow.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    int edgeDrawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
    Drawable androidEdge = getResources().getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
    androidEdge.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); 
}
```

Comment: I am targeting version 16 and above so do I need the whole if-else part? And where would this code go? in my onCreate?

Comment: @iqueqiorio Yes, it would be necessary. And it can go wherever you have access to the `ListView` instance (probably `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` if it's a Fragment).

Comment: I added the last block of your code into my `onCreate()` but I don't see any difference is there something I am missing?. And I see this in the logical `Could not find method android.widget.EdgeEffect.setColor, referenced from method `

Comment: @iqueqiorio You need to target API level 21 to use that part.

Comment: I have this set in my app.gradle `targetSdkVersion 21` and `compileSdkVersion 21`

Comment: @iqueqiorio Huh? Strange. `setColor()` was added in 21, should be available. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html#setColor%28int%29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66797/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-matiash).

Comment: It is working for API 21 but not below when the else statement is called? Do I need to get the API from github and import it?

Comment: @iqueqiorio Sorry, I didn't understand that last question. :(

Comment: see the chat to explain it

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change this default light blue color?

you have to create `StateListDrawable`  and set it as the `selector` for the `ListView`. the answer of matiash is good and I do not want to explain it again.

> change the color of the fuzzy stuff that comes up at the bottom of a
>   ListView when you continue to scroll down

[setCacheColorHint (int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setCacheColorHint%28int%29)

> Also how do you change the tap down color of the action bar back
>   button

```
<style name="actionbarCustomBackground" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/actionbar_item_background</item>
</style>
```

then in the actionbar_item_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: how do you do the action bar tap down color programatically

Comment: I think you can not do it programmatically because as I have searched there is no method for example called `setSelectableItemBackground`

Answer (score -2):

You can set row's background dynamically in `getView(..)` method.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
           .......... //your code
           view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)


        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I want to set the onTapDown color