# react-native android: How to change the color of ListView "end of scroll" animation?

Tags: android, react-native

How can I change the color of the animation?

[image]

Comment: this color depends on your current `Theme`. Not sure about react though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The color is based on your `accentColor` in your `AppTheme`.

To change it, change your `AppTheme` (generally in `res/values/styles.xml`) to:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#F00</item>   <-- change to color
    <!-- Status Bar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</item>
    <!-- Details color -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
</style>
```

Beware it's an global app change, every scrollview bounce animation will have this color.

Answer (score 3):

To change only the overflow animation color, use `android:colorEdgeEffect`. Otherwise it will be inherited from the `colorPrimary` in AppTheme.

The accepted answer should be changed to specify colorPrimary instead of colorAccent.

See answer here: [android lollipop scrollview edge effect color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104521/android-lollipop-scrollview-edge-effect-color)

Comment: This can't be applied on a per `<ScrollView>` basis, and is not react native specific is it?

Comment: Thanks Grey for sharing this info with us RN folks, I'm sure it will help us in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside `android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#E53644</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

if someone is using expo managed app, it's not supported by expo yet, but there's a workaround.

you'd need to `expo eject` -> to transition to [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/). then as said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61192054/5736491) within `android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml` add
`<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#E53644</item>`.

now the worst part which took me hours to figure out - you'll have 2 themes generated by default the `AppTheme` and `Theme.App.SplashScreen`, it didn't work until I've added it to splashscreen one :/. I've added it to both themes just in case. note that this specific change will work only when you run android specific native build `npm run android`, for more please read [this](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/)

Comment: any update on this using expo managed app in 2022? Would love to know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498193/how-to-change-android-edge-color-effect-in-expo-managed-workflow/72384994#72384994

Comment: @Kayee i'm glad they added support for that. thanks for sharing! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Expo managed workflow + react native paper with Material UI v3 and in debugging the color of the "ripple" was purple.

But luckily, when I test it over the Google Play Store, it was based on the primary color (or primary container color).

PS: I had similar issues with the color of dialog buttons and the app icon being not shown correctly.