# How to change Android edge color effect in Expo managed workflow?

Tags: expo

The edge effect has a color that occurs when you overscroll some list/scrollview.
I've found that you can change at "android:colorEdgeEffect" but I'm using managed workflow.

[image: Screenshot of edge color effect in Android]

Comment: I would love to know as well. Been stuck on this for a while

Comment: Any workarounds anyone apart from using expo eject (bare workflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this file and change it to your needs: ./plugins/withAndroidColorEdgeEffect.js:
https://github.com/wodin/rn-hce-test/blob/a89dcdbc6c642a839bce3ad6a58120627b668d5b/plugins/withAndroidColorEdgeEffect.js#L1

And reference it in your app.json file:

```
[
  "./plugins/withAndroidColorEdgeEffect",
  {
    "color": "#123456"
  }
],
```

And you will need to use the new "eas build -p android" instead of "expo build:android"

Source: https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-android-edgeeffect-color-in-scrollviews-and-flatlists-in-managed-workflow/64021/2